# Multiply two data frame columns

Tags: julia

So I tried this:

```
df[:new_col] = (df[:col_one ] .* [df[:col_two]])
```

It produces a wild result.

I then though to iterate row wise by access the data frame index:

```
v = Float64[]
for i in 1:nrow(df) 
    z = df[[i],[:col_one]] * df[[i],[:col_two]]
    append!(v,z)
end
```

This however does not work. Any ideas?

What are my options from here? Pull the data from a data frame and make a vector?

** Update **

```
df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = 10*rand(10), c = 10 * rand(10))
df[:new_d] = df[:b] .* df[:c]
```

For output:

```
julia> head(df)
6×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a │ b       │ c       │ new_d   │
├─────┼───┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 6.67916 │ 8.38096 │ 55.9778 │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 7.50056 │ 5.26593 │ 39.4974 │
│ 3   │ 3 │ 7.76419 │ 3.54361 │ 27.5133 │
│ 4   │ 4 │ 2.86521 │ 8.41335 │ 24.1061 │
│ 5   │ 5 │ 3.7417  │ 8.10884 │ 30.3409 │
│ 6   │ 6 │ 7.52014 │ 2.61603 │ 19.6729 │
```

Comment: `df[:new_col] = df[:col_one ] .* df[:col_two]` will work.

Comment: Ok - I'm not sure what happened the first time, I deleted the code and re-wrote it, before it was making many replications of the same thing

Comment: it was because you were doing something like: `[1,2,3] .* [[1,2,3]]`, which multiplies the second vector by 1, 2 and 3 (note that the second argument is a 1-element vector containing a vector).